# proving interval of convergence of series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$$ \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n^x \ln(n + x)} $$

Am I right that this series converging absolutely, while $ x \in(0;\infty) $ and don't converge on $(-1;0]$? (I don't consider complex value of logarithm).

I have hard times proving that so any hints or ideas are welcomed.

Comment: The series converges for $x\ge 0$.  Note that for $x=0$, $\frac{1}{\log(n)}$ monotonically decreases to $0$. It converges absolutely for $x>1$.

Comment: Hint: alternating series theorem

Comment: For $x=0$ we have to ignore the first term but if you do, you can also apply the alternating series test

Answer (score 2):

By alternating series test the given series converges for $x\ge0$ since $\frac{1}{n^x \ln(n + x)}\to 0$ and is decreasing.

The series converges absolutely for $x>1$ by limit comparison test with $\sum \frac 1{n^x}$.

For $x<0$ the series diverges since $|a_n|\to \infty$.